# Removing break between Bibliography and Chapter

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I'm writing a thesis using `\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}` and have a bibliography chapter. Currently, there is a Chapter called Bibliography and the rest of the page is blank. The next page is the Bibliography which reads "Bibliography" at the top again. Please see the images for further clarification. Also the code regarding that part is

```
\chapter{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or try abbrvnat or unsrtnat
\bibliography{Mendeley} % refers to example.bib
```

I would like to have Chapter 6, followed by the title "Bibliography", followed by the actual bibliography. Have tried different solutions I found here but with no success.

[image: Chapter page][image: Bibliography page]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: You don't need to create a new chapter for *Bibliography*

Comment: In the report class, the bibliography will by default be typeset as an unnumbered chapter. If you want it numbered, you can use `\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}`.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way is *patch* the *report class* (`report.cls`) to redefine `thebibliography` environment and to change `\chapter*{\bibname}` for `\chapter{\bibname}` (without obviously modifying the file `report.cls`). Let's remember that `\chapter*{}` creates chapters no numbered and `\chapter{}` numbers chapters.

To achieve this you can use the package `xpatch` (which requires internally to use `expl3.sty` and more *LaTeX 3* packages but no matter).

This change is possible with the command `\xpatchcmd{<command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%----------------------------------
% Redefine `thebibliography` environment
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{\chapter{\bibname}}{}{}
%---------------------------------
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
Here we cite\cite{key}
%\chapter{Bibliography} % unnecessary

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or try abbrvnat or unsrtnat
\bibliography{Mendeley} % refers to example.bib

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've tried this but can't achieve the "Chapter 6" followed by the heading "Bibliography" on the same page. If I use the code you provided, the bibliography still appears in the next page. If I enter a chapter it creates the same situation as in the original question. Also, perhaps I should add that this is in an Overleaf document.

Comment: Possibly `xpatch` package isn't correctly installed, please verify. My MWE runs perfectly with a suitable `key` in `\cite{key}` o with `\nocite{*}`

Comment: I've double checked, it does not work in Overleaf at least, maybe it's related to how they handle the package but not sure. I'm new to both Latex and Overleaf so I don't really know where the problem lies.

Comment: My [_MWE_](https://www.overleaf.com/10174653fcxfjswjnjyx) in Overleaf.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Your MWE works clearly but if I use the exact same code on mine it doesn't show the "Chapter X" part.